# Jquery Animate Effect reduce height by top and Bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

Hello StackOverflow I am trying to achieve an effect than reduce the height from 5 rem to 0 rem of a div.

Top Line

++++++++++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++++

Bottom Line

But moving at the same time the top line(border-top) and the bottom line(border-bottom) of the div like the up representation.

I was trying take a look to the plunkrer, but it does not move the top and bottom at same time:

`enter code here`http://plnkr.co/edit/wrchle0C3TXsqaS595VI?p=preview